# Expression for numerical amplification factor for Euler time integration and CD2 scheme for one degree hyperbolic function

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, time-integration

[image]

This is the expression to be derived but I am not getting the exact expression as given in the image. Is the given expression given for the implicit Euler method?

Here $N_c = c (\delta t)/h$ and $\tan(\beta_2) = N_c \sin (kh)$.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: @nicoguaro I have to derive the above equation, but I cannot understand how we are getting e^(-i beta 2) in the expression.

Comment: We could guess that much. But, what is the starting point? What is your differential equation, what is your discretization scheme?